# Python: Creating sublists based on group by result of data frame

Tags: python, list, dictionary, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with the following format:

```
    Timestamp       X      Y       Name   PlayerID
        0           0      0.5    Albert     1
       100          0      0.3    Albert     1 
       200          0      0.5    Albert     1
       300          0      0.6    Albert     1
        0          -22     4.8    Gregoire   2
       100         -32      5     Gregoire   2
       200         -11     3.4    Gregoire   2
       300         -23     4.4    Gregoire   2
```

What I need, is a dictionary with the keys being the Unique Timestamp values and the values of the dictionary need to be a list of lists containing the items that belong to that timestamp. That means:

```
        {'0': [ ['0','0.5','Albert','1'], ['-22','4.8','Gregoire','2'] ]
        '100': [ ['0','0.3','Albert','1'], ['-32','5','Gregoire','2'] ]
        '200': [ ['0','0.5','Albert','1'], ['-11','3.4','Gregoire','2'] ]
        '300': [ ['0','0.6','Albert','1'], ['-23','4.4','Gregoire','2'] ] }
```

I put the following code together but it only gives me a dictionary containing a the timestamps as keys and the values are a list of all the items that belong to that timestamp:

```
df.set_index('Timestamp').stack().groupby('Timestamp').apply(list).to_dict()
```

Output:

```
        {'0':  ['0','0.5','Albert','1','-22','4.8','Gregoire','2']
        '100': ['0','0.3','Albert','1','-32','5','Gregoire','2'] 
        '200': ['0','0.5','Albert','1','-11','3.4','Gregoire','2'] 
        '300': ['0','0.6','Albert','1','-23','4.4','Gregoire','2'] }
```

Is there a way to do this? I am guessing that something can be changed on that line of code to create sublists instead of one list but I have not figured out how. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this be okay with you:

```
df['Result'] = df.set_index('Timestamp').values.tolist()
df = df.groupby('Timestamp')['Result'].apply(list)

df.to_dict()

{0: [[0L, 0.5, 'Albert', 1L], [-22L, 4.8, 'Gregoire', 2L]],
 200: [[0L, 0.5, 'Albert', 1L], [-11L, 3.4, 'Gregoire', 2L]],
 100: [[0L, 0.3, 'Albert', 1L], [-32L, 5.0, 'Gregoire', 2L]],
 300: [[0L, 0.6, 'Albert', 1L], [-23L, 4.4, 'Gregoire', 2L]]}
```